# How to add a partial as an overlay on the whole angular app?

Tags: angularjs

I have a design where login screen looks completely different from the dashboard UI.
Once the user logs in he is shown a dashboard where he can control things.

Now,the login screen just occupies the whole view with a form box in centre.
once user logs in, then he is taken to the dashboard.

In our current approach we have kept login as a separate angular app and dashboard as separate as I am planning to use a view that changes except the sidebar and header as the ng-view for teh dashboard.

Currently the whole login screen is a separate app, which i feel is little weird when it comes to dealing with things, so is it possible to have an overlay which occupies the whole screen and goes away when the user logs in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. There are a couple options here. Some folks simply force you to the `/login` route until a successful login has been completed, token stored, etc. The other option is that you use a full-sized, absolutely-positioned container, with highest z-index, and place it on your main index.html. Until something changes, that's all you'll see. Then, use `ng-If` to remove that container once login is complete and a property of the view-model has been updated, such as `navModel.loginComplete=true;`